# HTML // jQuery - mute all audio sounds after reloading for 10secs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

How can I mute all audio sounds in my website after reloading the site for the first 10secs and then unmute again?

```
<audio id="musWrited" autoplay>
                <source src="sound/soundl.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
                    //
                </audio>
```

Is there an option with jQuery`?

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

in html:

```
<audio muted ....></audio>
```

and then in js:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $("audio").prop('muted', false);
}, 10000);
```